# how can i make chat position style that sender in left screen and receiver in right screen?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, textview, chat

[image: where I using Text View in scroll View]

where I using  Text View in scroll View
how can i make chat position style that sender in left screen and receiver in right screen?

Comment: use listview with getitemviewType, for this type

Comment: Aren't you doing that already? I see only arrows are not looking good.